# Reorder Parent-child relationship in same table - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, parent-child, hierarchical-data

I have below data in a table named CPGRPRULREL.

```
CPGRPRULREL_NUM | CPGRPRULREL_NUM_PRIOR | STATUS     | CNDQUALSRC_CD | CNDQUALTYP_CD | CPGRP_NUM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
41292           | 41289                 | Active     | PRODCNT       | PRODCNTUNQ    | 
41289           | 41286                 | Superseded | OTHERPG       |               | 118729
41286           | 41283                 | Superseded | SUBM          | VOLUME        | 
41283           | 41280                 | Superseded | OTHERPG       |               | 118729
41280           | 41277                 | Superseded | OTHERPG       |               | 118729
41277           | null                  | Superseded | PRODCNT       | PRODCNTALL    |
```

Here, CPGRPRULREL_NUM_PRIOR is a link to CPGRPRULREL_NUM (i.e. has foreign key constraint - kind of parent-child relationship).

I want to delete all with CPGRP_NUM = 118729. Before that, I need to update the values of CPGRPRULREL_NUM_PRIOR for remaining rows so that proper linking remains intact.

I need update query which will only update rows having CPGRP_NUM <> 118729 and have below data after running update.

```
CPGRPRULREL_NUM | CPGRPRULREL_NUM_PRIOR | STATUS     | CNDQUALSRC_CD | CNDQUALTYP_CD | CPGRP_NUM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
41292           | 41286                 | Active     | PRODCNT       | PRODCNTUNQ    | 
41289           | 41286                 | Superseded | OTHERPG       |               | 118729
41286           | 41277                 | Superseded | SUBM          | VOLUME        | 
41283           | 41280                 | Superseded | OTHERPG       |               | 118729
41280           | 41277                 | Superseded | OTHERPG       |               | 118729
41277           | null                  | Superseded | PRODCNT       | PRODCNTALL    |
```

Note that 2 rows with CPGRPRULREL_NUM 41292 and 41286 has CPGRPRULREL_NUM_PRIOR updated.

Comment: Why isn't `CPGRPRULREL_NUM = 41283` updated to 41277?

Comment: I am planning to delete all rows with CPGRP_NUM = 118729. So even if CPGRPRULREL_NUM = 41283 is not updated then fine. The aim is to have a propagated parent-child relationship in place even after deleting rows with CPGRP_NUM = 118729.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get the previous `CPGRPRULREL_NUM` where `CPGRP_NUM <> 118729`?

Something like this should work:

- Build the tree, starting with the first (null prior)
- If the previous `CPGRP_NUM` is 118729, then:

  - Return the previous `CPGRPRULREL_NUM_PRIOR` or `CPGRPRULREL_NUM` if this is null

Giving:

```
with rws as (
  select 41292 num, 41289 num_prior, null cpgrp_num from dual union all
  select 41289 num, 41286 num_prior, 118729 from dual union all
  select 41286 num, 41283 num_prior, null from dual union all
  select 41283 num, 41280 num_prior, 118729 from dual union all
  select 41280 num, 41277 num_prior, 118729 from dual union all
  select 41277 num, null  num_prior, null from dual 
), tree ( num, num_prior, cpgrp_num ) as (
  select * from rws
  where  num_prior is null
  union all
  select r.num, 
         case
           when t.cpgrp_num = 118729 then nvl ( t.num_prior, t.num ) 
           else r.num_prior
         end num_prior, r.cpgrp_num 
  from   rws r
  join   tree t
  on     t.num = r.num_prior
)
  select * from tree;

NUM         NUM_PRIOR    CPGRP_NUM   
   41277       <null>       <null> 
   41280        41277       118729 
   41283        41277       118729 
   41286        41277       <null> 
   41289        41286       118729 
   41292        41286       <null>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hierarchical subquery to find leaf value for each entry:

```
update cpgrprulrel c
  set CPGRPRULREL_NUM_PRIOR =
    (select CPGRPRULREL_NUM_PRIOR from cpgrprulrel
      where connect_by_isleaf = 1
      start with CPGRPRULREL_NUM = c.CPGRPRULREL_NUM_prior and cpgrp_num = 118729
      connect by prior CPGRPRULREL_NUM_prior = CPGRPRULREL_NUM and cpgrp_num = 118729)
  where cpgrp_num is null
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d4db1c00b22432591ddc54d71f924a28)</sup>**

Then you can delete unwanted rows.